# Mysql Best way to check date and insert division of payments

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, entity-relationship

I am designing a payments table for students where available payment terms are Monthly, Quarterly, Semestral, and Annual. Grade levels are from Elementary to Senior Highschool. This is the first time im designing tables involving money and schedules of payment. I know there's a need to get the sum, check the date for penalty and divide the tuition fee based on the selected payment term.

Where do I start?

**PaymentTerm**

```
id PK
term
```

**gradelevel_fee**

```
id
gradelevel_id
fee_id
```

**Student_Tuition**

```
id PK
sum(gradelevel_fees)
balance
paymentterm_id
```

**student_payments**

```
id
student_id
payment_id
```

**payment**

```
id
amountOfPayment
dateOfPayment
```

Where or how can i implement the checking of due date?
Should I put the due date under the `student_tuition` table?

Anything important that i missed?

I'd appreciate any suggestion.

Thanks.

Comment: because you will have different payment structures that constitute one to many relationship with student_tuition (e.g. multiple due dates) you probably don't want to put it there.  you might consider a Scheduled_Payments table then link that to student_tuition.  Its accounting.  So you need to handle debits and credits.  Debits they bought something and owe money credits they actually pay

Comment: What do you mean due date, due date for what?

Comment: @reds I'm referring to the due date of payment based on payment term for possible penalties of late payment.

Comment: you can put the due date here student_payments

Comment: no no sorry i think its not good in there. its in payment term

Answer (score 0):

The Due date must be put into table which not repeating the student_id, you can put it in your primary table, or in any table which is storing a record without any student_id duplication.

Its good to be placed in PaymentTerm table.

Hope it helps